# Only half of an <a> tag is linked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create two column boxes with clickable headers. I have everything setup and working but when I was testing I realized only half of the header was clickable. On the left column, the left half is clickable. On the right column, the right half is clickable. The 'a' tag applies to the entire header.

```
<section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="item-block">
                    <a href="#"><h3 class="block-header">#</h3></a>
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item-block">
                    <a href="#"><h3 class="block-header">#</h3></a>
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="item-block">
                    <a href="#"><h3 class="block-header">#</h3></a>
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item-block">
                    <a href="#"><h3 class="block-header">#</h3></a>
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I have added a picture of the layout. At the top of each item-block is a block-header which is the blue bar. The red part is the part that is linked. The blue part does nothing.
[image]

css:

```
.item-block {
    border: 2px solid #0026FF;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size:1.2em;
}

.block-header {
    text-align:center;
    background:#0026FF;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}

.item-block .block-header a {
    color:white;
    display:block;
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this so the entire header is clickable?

Comment: Have you tried setting your <a>'s to display:block?

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Something else must be causing this then, I created a codepen based on your example and it works fine: http://codepen.io/stufu/pen/JXxqLv

Comment: I've figured out the issue and fixed it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was another part of my page. Lower down on the page was a centered column that overlapped anything in the center of the page, making those halves not work properly. I changed the `z-index` of the dual columns to put it above the centered column and it works properly now.